# Массовое обновление полей в постах по расписанию в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, acf

Имеется кастомный тип записи в котором хранятся 14 записей, (первая неделя с ПН по ВС и вторая неделя с ПН по ВС) у каждой записи есть поле "номер недели" - 1 или 2, а также используя acf создан repeater, который в строке имеет название и 2 числовых поля, первое постоянно меняется, а второе поле - поле к которому нужно привести значение исходя из первого поля по расписанию (например, раз в час). Использую wp_cron, получилось что то такое.

```
$parameters = array(
    'post_type_schedule' => 'schedule'
);
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'hook_update_schedule_everyweek',  $parameters ) )
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'user_everyweek', 'hook_update_schedule_everyweek', $parameters );

add_action( 'hook_update_schedule_everyweek', 'update_schedule', 99, 1 );

function update_schedule( $post_type_schedule) {
    // здесь получаю 7 из 14 постов где номер недели предыдущий (в данном случае 1)
    $prev_week = 1;
    $posts_last_week = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'schedule',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'number-week',
                'value' => $prev_week
            )
        )
    ));
    // дальше нужно каким то образом пробежаться по массиву всех строк по всем постам и заменить значение
    // взяв из count в той же строке и записать в remain
    foreach ($posts_last_week->$posts as $post_i => $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $i = 0;
        while (have_rows('schedules', $post->ID)) {
            the_row();
            $row = get_row();
            $i++;
            $row['remain'] = get_sub_field('count');
            update_row('schedules', $i, $row);
        }
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Использую плагин acf, то ли не разобрался как обновлять поля в репитере, то ли так делать вообще нельзя с помощью его методов. Подскажите как можно это сделать?

Comment: А что не так с этим кодом? Какая ошибка?

Comment: 1. проверьте, что у вас не отключен wp_cron в конфиге. другие задачи по расписанию срабатывают? запланированные записи, например. 2. в `wp_schedule_event()` вторым аргументом вы передаёте "user_everyweek". Проверьте, что вы где-то создали этот интервал самостоятельно. Заодно проверьте, что сделали это правильно

Comment: Cron работает, интервал работает, проверил, переписав функцию под отправку письма (первое что пришло в голову). С кодом все вроде так, как мне кажется, но вот поля не обновляются в репитере. Как были значения до обновления так и остаются. Ошибку, не знаю где можно отследить.

Comment: Вывел переменную `$row` в ней ключ в формате `field_5af6b8d3667bb`, а не как я задавал в админке `count` и `remain`. Следовательно `$row['remain'] = get_sub_field('count');` - это не работает т.к. ключа такого у `$row` нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переработал немного цикл. Нашел ошибку в условии цикла `foreach` и переработал цикл `while`, получилось следующее

```
foreach ($posts_last_week->posts as $post_i => $post) {
    $i = 0;
    while (have_rows('schedules', $post)) {
        the_row();
        $row = get_row(true);
        $i++;
        $row['remain'] = get_sub_field('count');
        $upd = update_row('schedules', $i, $row, $post);
    }
}
```